# Firebase- childByAutoID changing values for each child

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase application and I need to adjust the key-value pair "yesCount",  a child under a firebase autoID.  Each post has a yes count and I need to be able to adjust the yesCount of the correct child when a the button is pressed for each cell(coordinating to each post). 
Here is my firebase database tree

> post-items
>                -L31FSpR8vy2TsBZy3-1

```
         addedByUser: "user"

         noText: "NO"

         question: "Hello World?"

         yesCount: 0

     yesText: "YES"
```

post-items->childByAutoID()->yesCount
I need to be able to change the yesCount for each post under post-items, when I press a button on the corresponding table view cell. 
 My current idea is...

```
@IBAction func askTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    //post under childByAutoID
    let post = Post(question: daquestion, addedByUser: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "name") as! String, yesText: dayes, noText: dano, yesCount: 0)

    let postRef = dbRef.childByAutoId()
    let postKey = postRef.key
    var autoIDs = [""]
    autoIDs.insert(postKey, at: 0)

    print (" child id\(postKey)")

    postRef.setValue(post.toAnyObject())

    previousVC.tableView.reloadData()

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

to add the information, then to retrieve it ...

```
@IBAction func yesTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.Yescount = Yescount + 1
      dbRef.child("autoID").child("yesCount").setValue(Yescount)
    let childCount = dbRef.child("autoID").value(forKey: "yesCount") as! Int

    sender.setTitle("\(String(describing: childCount))", for: [])

    dbRef.observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in

    })

}
```

However this is not working(keep in mind both those segments of code are in seperate view controllers).  I am open to any solution ideas and would prefer any ideas that would not require restructuring my code and firebase database too much.

Comment: You could add the `postKey` as a String to your `Post` object, and then use `dbRef.child("\(somePost.postKey)yesCount")` to set the new value.

Comment: I was able to add postKey to the object but when i try to set the new value it creates a new child under "post-items", it doesnt change the existing child "yesCount" which is under "postKey" which is under "post-items"

Comment: @JenPerson the above comment